# Unable to join channel on Hyperleger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm having trouble with the [BYFN](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html) tutorial. I managed to do it without problems, and now I'm trying to change some things on the configuration files. I configured 6 orgs, and I'm trying to create a channel with two of them. When I get to the command to join a channel, I'm getting this error:

`Error: proposal failed (err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = access denied: channel [] creator org [Client1MSP])`

Here are my configuration files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tutc4pla6jlygej/my_network.zip?dl=1

The commands I'm running from start to finish are on COMMANDS.txt. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem.

By using:

`docker ps
 docker logs <container_id>` on the peer container that was failing to join the channel, I was able to read this error on the log: `expected MSP ID Org1MSP, received Client1MSP`

Which led me to the `docker-compose-base.yaml` file, where I found some lines I forgot to change to reflect the different org names.